# Android: Error inserting fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm testing a simple fragment code but its not working. anyone can help?
There's nothing happen when the button is clicked.
When i try to place the onclicklistener in FrameLayout.java, it's becoming error when running the program.

### FrameLayoutActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FrameLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frame_layout);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, fragment).commit();
    }

    public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

        static ExampleFragment newInstance() {
            ExampleFragment f = new ExampleFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world,
                    container, false);

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

### frame_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/simple_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/window2x"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

</FrameLayout>
```

### hello_world.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### HelloWorld.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello_world);

        final Button inner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        inner.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Comment: why did you call your activity FrameLayout?

Comment: This type of errors occurs when you have already set your view in xml file and you are trying to add that view also dynamically in your Activity.

Comment: @blackbelt: is there a problem with the name?

Comment: you can name it the way you like more, but imo appending the suffix Layout to an Activity is a bit confusing

Comment: okay, i'll change it. i name it that way because i'm testing framelayout. besides that, do you know why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world,
                    container, true);

            return v;
        }
```

the third parameter has to be `false` not `true`. Android is taking care to put that view you returned inside the `FrameLayout` you provide to the add method